# Intra Department Transfer

Tags: software-industry, human-resources

Need you help with understanding Intra departmental transfer.

I am currently working in Recruitment Dept of an IT company. I did training on SAP Functional area. Now I am interested in moving towards other side of the table that is in SAP HR.

My current manager is not aware of my SAP aspiration. I have been star performer through-out my 2.8 yrs of exp with this firm.

I am scared if I will ask for transfer my manager wont approve. 
I am thinking first to speak to the manager under whom SAP practice been taken care.

Not sure how I can pitch my transfer. Please help me.. with your suggestion

Comment: Are you sure your manager is not aware of your SAP aspiration becoz it seems you took training under same organization ?

Comment: Yeah.. I did training from an institute not from my company.

Comment: ****comments removed**** Please don't use comments to answer the question. Comments are intended to seek clarity or help improve a post. For more details, please see [help].

Answer (score 3):

Do not go behind your current manager's back. Make sure you have documentation (reviews, emails, etc) about how well you've performed.

Tell your current manager about your career goals and that you're serious enough about this transfer that you went and got your own training. Your manager may not want to let you go and could start treating you negatively (Some people are petty and vindictive) or realize you want to improve yourself. Hopefully you won't be faulted for wanting more out of your career or at least go into the type of work you'll enjoy more.

You want to make sure the new manager for the job you'll be applying has access to your performance records to this date. This will be an attempt to make sure your current manager doesn't start giving you a bad appraisal. It would look very suspicious.

Think about how you will work in your current position if you do not get the transfer. Hopefully your boss will be happy to keep a good employee and neither of you will have any bad feelings towards one another.

Answer (score 2):

usually when someone tells me they want to move to a new department, that means they are either going to find that work here, or they are going to quit to find it elsewhere.

If your worried that he wont let you move, have you thought about seeking employment elsewhere?

If you have been doing a great job for the last 3 years, then it seems that your manager would be foolish to lose you, and not move you within the company.